# What's the possible reason that makefile would skip making one executable?

Tags: makefile

I try to then execute exact same compilation command for that skipped file and it is being correctly compiled. But when I put it in make file it is just skipped. Every other file is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing the `makefile` (which you haven't provided), we can only guess (though I'd like to think it's an *educated* guess).

Since `make` works by checking file timestamps to see if they need rebuilding, that's one thing to look at. If the timestamp of a target is later than that of all dependencies, the target won't be built.

The other is to ensure your top level rule actually has a dependency on what you're trying to build, somewhere in the hierarchy. By that I mean the ruleset:

```
all: xyzzy

xyzzy:
    touch xyzzy

plugh:
    touch plugh
```

with the command `make all` will *never* touch `plugh` because it's not in the dependency hierarchy off `all`.

And `make` generally provides command line options for debugging (like the `-d` flag in GNU Make) which will tell you *why* it's making the decisions it's making. If you want to understand what's happening, you should probably use them,a s it makes it that much easier to debug your `makefile`.